# Laravel: getting data from index method in a controller with pagination or without pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, controller

I am using paginate() method to get paginated data in index method in controller but sometimes I need whole data so I wrote code like this.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->page === 'all') {
        $posts = Post::all();
    } else {
        $posts = Post::paginate(10);
    }

    return response([
        'posts' => $posts
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

So if I want to get all data I send page value as `all`.
If I want paginated data I send page value as `integer`.

It works fine but just wondering if there are any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further simplify the code you're using.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $page = $request->page;
    return response([
        'posts' => $page === 'all' ? Post::all() :  Post::paginate($page)
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid load several time of model instance.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $post = Post::query();
  $data = ($request->page === 'all') ? $post : $post->paginate(10);
  return response()->json(['posts' => $data], 200);
}
```